# How to list predefined preprocessor variables with nagfor

Tags: compilation, fortran, preprocessor, nag-fortran

I'd like to get a list of the preprocessor variables that are predefined when using the nagfor Fortran compiler. The equivalent with gfortran is

```
gfortran -E -dM foo.F90
```

but with

```
nagfor -F -Wp,-dM foo.F90
```

I get

```
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 5.3(854)
fpp: warning: bad option: -dM , ignored.
```

I looked in the [nagfor documentation](http://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r53_doc/nagfor.html) and the [fpp documentation](http://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r53_doc/fpp.html) but couldn't find the answer.

What I'm looking for is some variable to determine that the file is being compiled with nagfor, so the equivalent of the gfortran `__GFORTRAN__`, the ifort `__INTEL_COMPILER` and the pgf90 `__PGI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buried in the documentation for fpp I find ([4.5.4 Macro definition](https://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r62_doc/manual/compiler_4_5.html#MACRO) for the release 6.2, section 5.4 of the question's linked documentation for version 5.3)

> The macro NAGFOR is defined by default.

Sure enough

```
#ifdef NAGFOR
  print '("nagfor says hello")'
#endif
end
```

has the desired result when passed through the preprocessor.  In my case the macro takes the value `1`, but I don't know how consistent that may be.

As [Themos Tsikas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9261351/themos-tsikas) comments, there are [also the macros](https://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r62_doc/manual/compiler_4_3.html#FPP_DESCRIPTION) `__NAG_COMPILER_RELEASE` and `__NAG_COMPILER_BUILD` which do take well-defined values.

Comment: It's documented, therefore It Will Always Work.[https://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r62_doc/manual/compiler_4_0.html]

Comment: Will it always have value `1`?

Comment: Not necessarily, but see also [https://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r62_doc/manual/compiler_4_3.html] and the __NAG_COMPILER_RELEASE and __NAG_COMPILER_BUILD macros

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the answer with those other macros and the 6.2 docs.